# compress file with GZIP in java

Tags: java, text, binary, format, gzip

I tried to read a txt file with the buffered input stream, and compress it with GZIP, it worked. However, when I try to extract the compressed file with the zip, the file seems in unreadable binary format, how do I solve this problem?  The following is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    compressWithGZIP(SAVE_PATH2, SAVE_PATH3);
    //uncompressWithGZIP(SAVE_PATH3 + "compressed.gz", SAVE_PATH4);
}

private static void uncompressWithGZIP(String oripath, String outputPath) {
    BufferedInputStream bi = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bo = null;
    try {
        bi = new BufferedInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(oripath)));
        bo = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputPath));
        int c;
        while ((c = bi.read()) != -1) {
            bo.write(c);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bi != null) {
                bi.close();
            }
            if (bo != null) {
                bo.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}

private static void compressWithGZIP(String filePath, String outputPath) {
    if (outputPath == null || outputPath.isEmpty()
            || !outputPath.endsWith(".gz")) {
        outputPath += "compressed.gz";
    }

    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bo = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        bo = new BufferedOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(outputPath)));
        int c;
        while ((c = br.read()) != -1) {
            bo.write(c);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
            if (bo != null) {
                bo.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classical mistake.

**DO. NOT. EVER. USE. A. READER. TO. READ. BINARY. DATA.**.

A `Reader` interprets data read from a file as potential characters using a character decoding process. There *is* a reason why Java defines both Reader vs InputStream and Writer vs OutputStream.

If you deal with binary data, use InputStream and OutputStream. **NEVER** Reader or Writer.

In other words your problem is here:

```
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    bo = new BufferedOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(outputPath)));
```

Use an `InputStream`, not a `Reader`, to read from the source file.